# Transporter move through wall

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model I use a transporter which uses free navigation. If it is right, the transporters can not move through walls, the strange thing is that in my model at one point somehow the transporter is able to move through a wall?

He slips through the wall somewhere at the red circled section, when I check the simulation. (see screenshot, blue is the transporter)

When I look at the model, I also see that there is no gap or something (see second image). Am I'm overlooking something (maybe something about that I've multiple floors)? or is it a bug? Does somebody know how to fix it.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For other people facing this problem, when having a low turn radius (0.01) and no speed limit near obstacle in your transporterfleet, it is possible to move through walls, if you change this the problem is solved!